# Decompose 3d vector into 3 vectors with equal (or other ratio) length, each in a different ortogonal plane

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to solve a problem with a mechanical (actually game) application.

I have a vector/normal in 3 dimensions (so with x,y,z).
I want to decompose this vector into 3 vectors, where each vector should lie in it's own plane which is perpendicular to one of the world x/y/z axes.
Or said differently, each of the 3 vectors has one component set to 0, x for the first, y for the second, z for the last.
Additionally, I want the resulting 3 vectors to be the same length, which is what makes this hard for me to solve. Even better would be if they can be a(any) given ratio, like 1:1:3.

I'm not sure how to calculate the values for the 3 vectors based on a given input vector.
My (vector) math is ok, but not that advanced :)

I'm not sure if this is an 'easy' problem, or actually hard or impossible :)

Note: For those interested, this is useful when you have three rotors along the three x/y/z axes, and each rotor has a thruster. The three vectors give you the angle and thrust for each rotor/thruster to actually get the input 'thrust' vector with them :)

And just to add my thoughts so far, I think these are the equations involved, just not sure how to solve them together:

```
input vector: (vx,vy,vz)
result vectors:
(v1x,v1y,0)
(v2x,0,v2z)
(0,v3y,v3z)

vx = v1x + v2x
vy = v1y + v3y
vz = v2z + v3z

l1 = sqrt(v1x^2 + v1y^2)
l2 = sqrt(v2x^2 + v2z^2)
l3 = sqrt(v3y^2 + v3z^2)

l1 = l2 = l3
```

**Upd** Hmm, I wonder if what I'm trying to do is correct, once the thrust vector is close to, or especially in line with an axis, it's still possible to have the three vectors the same length, but at that point one is adding (close  to) 0 useful force, and the other two are just compensating that. Not very efficient.. I guess I either want to tweak their ratio based on closeness to an axis, or maybe I'm better off with the simpler solution of just looking at each x/y/z component only. E.g. v1x = vx/2 and v2x = vx/2.